# Extract records from MySQL Based on Results from other Table

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the table layout:

Table 1:
Id  -  U1  -  U2  -  Status

Table 2
Id  -  U1  -  U2  -  Type  -  Status

I need to select all the records in table 2 to where U1 or U2 matches the numbers found in U1 or U2 in table 1 with Status set to confirmed.

This is what I have, but it is far from efficient, and doesnt order the records based on when they were created, and lumps all the record associated with each ID together.

```
 $q = "SELECT `U1`, `U2` FROM `Table1` WHERE `U1='{VALUE}' OR `U2`='{VALUE}' AND `Status`='Confirmed';
```

{Value} = prestored value that we have. After executing that query (while looping through) and determining which value from Table 1 does **not** equal our predefined value (making it $ur ):

```
 $q2 = "SELECT * FROM `Table2` WHERE `U1`='".mysql_real_escape_string($ur)."' OR `U2`='".mysql_real_escape_string($ur)."'";
```

Comment: for ordering on creation date, you need to have a field holding that creation date, mysql otherwise doesn't keep track of that information. Maybe on Id if it is defined as `AUTO INCREMENT`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single query (untested):

```
SELECT T2.* FROM (
    SELECT U2 AS VALUE FROM Table1 
    WHERE U1 = :value AND STATUS = "Confirmed"
    UNION
    SELECT U1 AS VALUE FROM Table1 
    WHERE U2 = :value AND STATUS = "Confirmed"
) AS T1, Table2 AS T2
WHERE T2.U1 = T1.VALUE  OR T2.U2 = T1.VALUE
ORDER BY T2.ID
```

Comment: You, my friend, are brilliant! +1 for you! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your statement:

*I need to select all the records in table 2 to where U1 or U2 matches the numbers found in U1 or U2 in table 1 with Status set to confirmed.*

```
SELECT T2.*
FROM Table2 T2
   JOIN Table1 T1 ON 
      (T2.U1 = T1.U1 OR T2.U1 = T1.U2 OR T2.U2 = T1.U1 OR T2.U2 = T1.U2)
WHERE T2.Status = 'confirmed'
```

Comment: I have tested this. Not sure if this are the correct results. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5dedc/1/0

Comment: @hek2mgl -- depends on OPs desired results -- a little confused by requirements.  This should be close though :)  Thanks for the fiddle!

Comment: 'a little confused by requirements' -> me too! .. sqlfiddle rocks!! :)

Comment: @sgeddes: Yea, sorry about the confusion. This is almost what I need, but I need to be able to match what it gets from Table1 with a predefined value (this is actually where table one comes in). I just need the records from Table one where a certain number appears in U1 or U2, then do the same with Table 2 using the results from Table 1.

Comment: So, say these numbers were associated with the number '8' in Table one: 9, 20, 34. I then need all the records from Table two where those number appear in U1 or U2.

Comment: Yea, the `Id` column does Auto-Increment. But, I still need to only select the records from Table 2 that have U1 or U2 that match one of the numbers from Table1.